# Rails 4: Passing a local variable to a js.erb file from a partial containing a form_for helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I pass a local variable from a form_for helper to a js file?

I have the following file called _subscribe.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @subscription, :url => {:controller => "subscriptions", :action => "create"} do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :group_id, group.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: "btn btn-primary subscribe_btn" %>
<% end %>
```

The group local variable gets passed from a do block into this form and works (html only up until now). I want to turn this into an ajax call so i added `remote: true` to the form and added the file create.js.erb to the subscriptions folder:

```
$("#new_subscription").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('subscriptions/unsubscribe', locals: { group: group } )) %>")
```

and this is my subscriptions controller create action:

```
def create
    @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.create(:group_id => params[:group_id])
    @subscription.save
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to groups_path, flash[:success] = "You have successfully subscribed to this group" }
      format.js  
    end
  end
```

However now I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `group' for #<#<Class:0x007fe7ecfd4950>:0x007fe7ecfde7e8>):
    1: $("#new_subscription").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('subscriptions/unsubscribe', locals: { group: group } )) %>")
  app/views/subscriptions/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_subscriptions_create_js_erb__3184685282411376061_70317032458920'
  app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

The group local variable is not being passed from the form_for to the create.js.erb on submit. I have tried everything in the past 4 hours but am still coming up short. How do I fix this issue and pass the local variable from the _subscribe.html.erb partial to the create.js.erb file?

Edit:

More code... first my subscriptions controller create action:

```
def create
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.create(:group_id => @group.id)
    @subscription.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to groups_path }
      format.js 
    end
  end
```

and destroy action:

```
def destroy
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.find_by(group_id: @group.id)
    @subscription.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to groups_path }
      format.js
    end
   end
```

& create.js.erb

```
$("#subscribe_button").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('subscriptions/unsubscribe', locals: { group: @group } )) %>")
```

& destory.js.erb

```
$("#unsubscribe_button").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('subscriptions/subscribe', locals: { group: @group } )) %>")
```

I am still getting the following error in the logs:

```
Started POST "/subscriptions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-20 22:23:39 +0000
Processing by SubscriptionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "group_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Subscribe"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'b0afd34150d0c021a1e4d0dfa357107a2aa59f00' LIMIT 1
  Group Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Subscription Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "subscriptions" WHERE ("subscriptions"."group_id" = 1 AND "subscriptions"."user_id" = 2) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "subscriptions" ("created_at", "group_id", "role", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:23:39 UTC +00:00], ["group_id", 1], ["role", "pending"], ["updated_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:23:39 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 2]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Subscription Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "subscriptions" WHERE ("subscriptions"."group_id" = 1 AND "subscriptions"."id" != 96 AND "subscriptions"."user_id" = 2) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered subscriptions/_unsubscribe.html.erb (100.3ms)
  Rendered subscriptions/create.js.erb (101.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 120ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `group' for #<#<Class:0x007fdc05a244a8>:0x007fdc0545b350>):
    1: <%= debug group %>
    2: <div id="unsubscribe_button"> 
    3: <%= button_to "Unsubscribe", subscription_path(group), :remote => true, :method => 'delete', class:  "btn subscribe_btn" %>
    4: </div>
  app/views/subscriptions/_unsubscribe.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_subscriptions__unsubscribe_html_erb__4479900334468069300_70291478478720'
  app/views/subscriptions/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_subscriptions_create_js_erb__1667797080065562395_70291478425360'
  app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

You can clearly see that the @group is set in the create action and is successfully creating a subscription but the local variable is not being set in the js.erb files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't.  Execution ends when the current request ends, i.e. when the form is rendered.  The .js.erb view template is not called until the form is submitted, starting a new request.

You'll have to create an instance variable e.g. `@group = however_you_get_the_group` in the controller's create action to make it visible to the .js.erb view, and reference as such: `locals: { group: @group }`

Comment: Does `locals: { group: @group }` make the group local variable available in the partial it is passed to? Your suggestion didn't work for me?

Comment: Yes. However you must make sure that `@group` exists when you pass it, or you'll get nil for `group` in your partial.

Comment: Hey I marked your answer as correct as technically it is. I thought I had an answer but came back to this today and I am still running into an issue with the local variables not being passed from the js files. I have updated my question above to include subscription controller code.

Comment: Usage of the "locals" key in render is unnecessary most of the time, try changing to this: `$("#subscribe_button").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('subscriptions/unsubscribe', group: @group )) %>")` though I'm not sure it will make a difference

Comment: You could also try debugging the state of `local_assigns` in the partial before you attempt to access `group` to see what locals are present

Comment: You absolute legend. Removing the locals key worked. I knew it would be something simple like that. Can't believe I didn't stumble on it considering all the combination I ended up trying.

Comment: Nice! It's probably because the api's gotten convoluted when they made the `partial` key optional in `render`, but only in some cases.  It would probably also work by adding the `partial` key: `$("#subscribe_button").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'subscriptions/unsubscribe', locals: { group: @group } )) %>")
`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you are in the `create` action, you don't have the variables that you set in the previous action.

So you need to set again the `@group` instance variable and then use it in your `create.js.erb` template.

```rb
def create
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.create(:group_id => @group.id)
  @subscription.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to groups_path, flash[:success] = "You have successfully subscribed to this group" }
    format.js
  end
end
```

```js
$("#new_subscription").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('subscriptions/unsubscribe', locals: { group: @group } )) %>")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. This still throws the same error. I have added more code to the question above. The @group variable is being set in the create action but not in the create.js.erb file (or at least it is not being passed as a local variable as desired).

Comment: If you see the new error it says that the `group` variable or method is undefined, and not that is nil. So maybe the problem is in the way you are sending the attributes to the render method. I think that you need to send also the `partial` key, like: `render(partial: 'subscriptions/unsubscribe', locals: { group: @group } )`

Comment: The problem was to do with the keys in the js code. Look to the above answer... Thanks for your time and help.